# how to chop a string till "_" in ssrs using a cube report

Tags: string, reporting-services

I have a string (46318g_orchidpinkminisneakpead) Here i want to chop off the part till "_" and give me the result. So my result should be "orchidpinkminisneakpead"  now what expression should I use to get this value in ssrs and the chopped string size do differ sometimes it can be 7 char sometimes it can be 8,9 also.

I am building the report using a cube so no changes can be done on the back-end.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=MID(Fields!YourField.Value,
InStr(Fields!YourField.Value,"_")+1,
LEN(Fields!YourField.Value)
)
```

In your case,

```
=MID(
 "46318g_orchidpinkminisneakpead",
 InStr("46318g_orchidpinkminisneakpead","_")+1,
 LEN("46318g_orchidpinkminisneakpead")
)
```

should produce `orchidpinkminisneakpead`

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I did try that it is not giving me any image just a red cross

Comment: @sam, where are you trying to use the expression, and what is the string you are passing to it?

Comment: in the text box i have inserted an image and in the image properties i'm giving the values. I'm passing a field

Comment: @sam, If you are trying to use this expression to retrieve an image by its name check the name of the image matches with the name produced by the expression. Note the expression produces what you are asking in your question. Good luck.

Comment: yes I would like to retrieve an image i have given the field name

Comment: @sam, Are you sure the image name is the same as the value produced by the expression?

Comment: yes an http link must be appended to it so the expression I used is "http://s7d.scene7.com/is/image" & mid(Fields!image.Value, Instr(Fields!image.Value,"_")+1, LEN(Fields!image.Value))

Comment: @sam, Like you say, it is a http link, you have to specify that: `"http://s7d.scene7.com/is/image/" & mid(Fields!image.Value, Instr(Fields!image.Value,"_")+1, LEN(Fields!image.Value))`